# Get all checkbox id on form submit php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form having multiple checkbox like this.

```
$res_rooms=$this->product_model->roomType();
foreach($res_rooms->result() as $val)
{
   <input type="checkbox" name="room_list[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"id="room_list<?php echo $val;?>">
}
```

On Form submit I need all checkbox id on my controller whether it is checked or not.

Comment: Loop the checkbox array and get values and check it s checked or no;

Comment: it show only checked id not all. @itzmukeshy7

Comment: @developersaumya, use IDs then (increment id, like room_list0,room_list1, etc...), loop through all checkboxes, and add condition to check values...

Comment: @nevermind please write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to post ids here:

here

```
1) id contains room_list <?php echo $val;?>:
2) name contains room_list[]
3) Value contains <?php echo $val; ?>
```

Now you id is consist of room_list and  `$val`.
`$val` you are already getting in post as a value

So in **$POST data** you can dynamically generate id of all checkbox

ex.

```
foreach($_POST['room_list'] as $rooms) {
 $id = 'room_list'+$rooms; // here $rooms contains the `$val` values
}
```

> Create hidden input fields to get all checkbox values:

```
$res_rooms=$this->product_model->roomType();
foreach($res_rooms->result() as $val)
{
   <input type="hidden" name="room_list_hidden[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="room_list[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>"id="room_list<?php echo $val;?>">
}
```

So in `$_POST['room_list_hidden']` you will get all ids

Comment: In $_POST['room_list'] you will only get all checked elements list

Comment: but i need all checkbox id either it checked or not

Comment: but rather than using checkboxes to get all ids, use same query $res_rooms=$this->product_model->roomType(); to get all room ids

Comment: or other way is create hidden input fields to get all ids.

Comment: thanks, It work $res_rooms=$this->product_model->roomType()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111917/discussion-between-developersaumya-and-jayesh-chitroda).

Answer (score 0):

If check-box is checked then you get that check-box and its value on server and you area using array of check-box so you get in array format.

to get all the ids on server side.

1. make a query which gives you all the ids on the server directly.
2. make hidden field for all ids so at the time of form submit you will

   $res_rooms=$this->product_model->roomType();
   foreach($res_rooms->result() as $val)
   {
       " />
       "id="room_list">
   }